# How to add non-native Python module in Yocto BSP with recipes proper way

Tags: python-3.x, yocto-recipe

I've found nice project https://github.com/NFJones/pipoe
Also made with it few recipes to download Python3 modules from PyPi and try to include them in my custom image.
Put all the recipes in ../sources/meta-custom/recpies-devtools/python
Single recipe looks like ***python3-gpsd-py3_0.3.0.bb***

```
SUMMARY = "Python 3 library for working with gpsd"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/MartijnBraam/gpsd-py3"
AUTHOR = "Martijn Braam <martijn@brixit.nl>"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://setup.py;md5=3e3cbe31a62516c437edc8135773c462"

inherit setuptools3 pypi

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "041ce56e8879e2104b4d54c8119cd529"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "2908d3bd78dfb6720ecfe22f97e139b5a4a198f38df3a77215cf644a33513192"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "gpsd-py3"

DEPENDS += " "
RDEPENDS_${PN} = ""

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

But anyway bitbake didn't find any recipe with single compilation as ***bitbake python3-gpsd-py3_0.3.0.bb***

How properly add non native Python3 modules in Yocto recipes ?
Also how to add custom Python apps in Yocto BSP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it after dig - your own recipes should be put in ***../sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python***

Comment: In the matter of facts - can be anywhere in custom meta-layer direcotry